# node.js+socket.io port not opening with ssl

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I am unable to connect a port via https. I earlier had a require('http') in my code and i changed it to require('http'), but it doesnt work. it still opens with http in the browser. Here is the code. I have gone through many forums but couldnt find an answer. my website has an ssl certificate(smartican.com)

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var util = require('util');
var url = require('url');

var DBWrapper = require('node-dbi').DBWrapper; 
var DBExpr = require('node-dbi').DBExpr; 
var dbConnectionConfig = { config};
dbWrapper = new DBWrapper( "pg", dbConnectionConfig );
dbWrapper.connect();

var app = express();

var connectedsockets = new Array();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = https.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port with https" + app.get('port'));
});
var io = socketio.listen(server);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
server = https.createServer({key:fs.readFileSync('key.pem'), cert:fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')},app).listen....
```

You pass your key and cert in as an object. This enables you to use your fancy ssl credentials.

Comment: thanks.. i was missing the private key and certificates for ssl